# Yarn doesn't recognise BlockFrost

Tags: blockfrost

[image]Can anyone help me with this kind of error? I'm running this tutorial.
https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js-examples/tree/master/examples/simple-transaction

Comment: Did you run 'yarn' as following https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js-examples/blob/master/examples/simple-transaction/README.md#how-to-use ?

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repository, you need to install the dependencies. They are not part of the git repository.

To do this with `yarn`, simply execute the `yarn` command in the `/simple-transaction` directory (without any parameters).